# Is 'vars().values()' guaranteed to return the values in the exact order they were passed?

Tags: python-3.x, arguments

I want to be sure that `vars().keys()` and `vars().values()` return the names and values of the input arguments in the exact order in which they are passed to the function.

I have executed the following test, which shows that the answer is yes:

```
def testKeys(a,c,b):
    print(vars().keys(),vars().values())

def testVals(a,b,c):
    print(vars().keys(),vars().values())

testKeys(1,2,3) # should print a,c,b,1,2,3
testKeys(1,3,2) # should print a,c,b,1,3,2
testVals(1,2,3) # should print a,b,c,1,2,3
testVals(1,3,2) # should print a,b,c,1,3,2
```

But I am not 100% sure of this, because `vars()` returns a dictionary, in which the order is not guaranteed I suppose.

Comment: `from collections import OrderedDict`

Comment: @alec: Thanks, but I'm looking for an answer, not for an alternative solution (also, whatever `vars()` return, I wish to handle exactly in that order, i.e., I cannot change the returned data to some OrderedDict or whatever).

Comment: In python 3.7+ the insertion order is kept, I believe.